# Cannot reindex with Searchkick

Tags: elasticsearch, searchkick

My database has over 3 million documents to be indexed. This is my setup:

Rails 4.2.0beta2 on Heroku. Using [Searchkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/) with [Found](https://addons.heroku.com/foundelasticsearch?utm_campaign=search&utm_medium=dashboard&utm_source=addons) Heroku addon.

These are the models that I indexed:

```
class Item
 searchkick text_start: [:n, :ot, :est]

 def search_data
        # as_json only: [:n, :ot, :est, :dst, :d, :a]
        {
            n: n,
            ot: detail.ot,
            est: detail.est,
            dst: dst,
            d: detail.d,
            a: detail.a
        }
 end
```

end

```
class User
     searchkick text_start: [:full_name]

     def full_name
         "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
     end

     def search_data
        {
            full_name: full_name
        }
     end
 end
```

.. by doing `rake searchkick:reindex:all`.

Now, I've noticed that our Elasticsearch cluster has only indexed half of my documents (~1.5M). I asked our cluster provider if there is any limit on number of documents and confirmed that there isn't. I don't know why it stopped at 1.5M (instead of indexing all 3 million). However, now I'm trying to index everything again and watch out for errors or something alike and this is the first thing it comes out (before indexing anything):

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `index' for #<Searchkick::Index:0x007fbb5308bf18>
    from /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/searchkick-0.8.6/lib/searchkick/index.rb:192:in `block in import_scope'
    from /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mongoid-4.0.1/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:648:in `yield_document'
    from /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mongoid-4.0.1/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:123:in `block in each'
    from /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/moped-2.0.3/lib/moped/cursor.rb:32:in `block in each'
    from /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/moped-2.0.3/lib/moped/cursor.rb:32:in `each'
    from /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/moped-2.0.3/lib/moped/cursor.rb:32:in `each'
    from /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/moped-2.0.3/lib/moped/query.rb:77:in `each'
    from /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mongoid-4.0.1/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:122:in `each'
    from /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mongoid-4.0.1/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:20:in `each'
    from /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/searchkick-0.8.6/lib/searchkick/index.rb:189:in `import_scope'
    from /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/searchkick-0.8.6/lib/searchkick/index.rb:158:in `reindex_scope'
    from /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/searchkick-0.8.6/lib/searchkick/model.rb:47:in `reindex'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
... 7 levels...
    from /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.1/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
    from /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.1/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
    from /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.1/lib/spring/application.rb:183:in `block in serve'
    from /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.1/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `fork'
    from /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.1/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `serve'
    from /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.1/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.1/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/borjagvo/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

Checking out cluster status once this error comes out, I see that a new index is created instead of "overriding" the old one: http://cl.ly/image/0I0v1a2T1N2W

What I'm doing wrong? Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.